# Should I use user_id (Primary Key) or user_name (Unique Index) To Insert and Fetch Data From Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am developing a user comments system in php mysql. Actually, My first preference is to use user_id(Primary Key) to fetch and insert data into mysql, but on some places I need to use user_name(Unique Index) to get data from mysql and to update or insert into it.

I want to ask that which is the most efficient way? If on some places,  I have to use user_name will it effect efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You have an index on both the user_id and user_name so they will both be fast, generally speaking (as you've not given details to the types used in both of these fields) the user_id will be faster as the index size would logically be smaller than the user_name field - but you're talking tiny differences.

Can i amuse that user_name is actually their login name and not their real name - as having a unique index on a real persons name will be problematic due to high probability of collisions.  If this is the case have you thought about hashing the name and then using that as an index?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `user_id` as a primary key, not the `user_name`, but whenever you are trying to insert or fetch the data based on `user_name`, you must use `user_id` in where clause, because I am sure there must be an `user_id` when there is an `user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

> We've just noticed a very strange thing on our production system.  A Unique Key on a crucial 
>   linking table was replaced with a Primary Key & performance improved dramatically!

reference :

[Here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4941517587762#41810011839090).